# How do I know the instance is ready when using AWS cloudformatoin to start EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am now using my script(Python) to send request checking the instance status after create the stack using AWS cloudformation.
But it seems not a good solution. Then I try using cfn-signal to check the instances' status, only to find out that when received signal the cloudformation stack is successfully created, but the EC2 instance is still being checked.

How do I know the instance is ready when using AWS cloudformatoin to start EC2 instance

Answer (score 2):

You can AWS’s WaitCondition for that. Basically, WaitCondition is used with CloudFormation templates to ensure required resources are running.

For more details [click here](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/working-with-waitcondition-on-awss-cloudformation/)

Following snippet is taken from the above mentioned article

> **What is WaitCondition and who needs it?**
>
> WaitCondition can be considered as a timed semaphore which pauses the execution of yourCloudFormation template and waits for a number of success signals before it continues a stack creation operation. There are scenarios where you need to pause the execution of your CloudFormation stack, such as resource dependencies or user experience. Some scenarios also include:
>   
>   - As a part of user experience, you want to pause completion of CloudFormation template and display of the output section until all resources are properly provisioned and in working state.
>   - There are resource dependencies where some additional scripts and packages on your instance must be properly configured before other AWS resources can contact them. For example, for successful backend configuration, a front end application should be in running state.
>   - An environment in which Active Directory should be in a running state before other instances perform authentication.
>   - A NAT instance should be in working state before private subnet instances try to fetch packages from the outside world.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, it helps a lot.

Comment: I have tried WaitCondition in my template. When the cloudformation stack successfully created, I switched to the EC2 instances manager to check instance's status. But it was still in the initializing progress. That's exactly what I worry about. The WaitCondition told me that the instance was ready to use, but the EC2 instances manager showed that the instance